# How to get screen to display a notification or indicator when Caps Lock is turned on or toggled?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, caps-lock

I'm on OS X Mountain Lion and would like to know how to do this.  I know the button has a light to indicate, but I'd like have and indication on the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CapSee](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33343/capsee) Notifies You When Caps Lock Is On!

The little app shows you huge icon when caps in on!

Comment: CapSee has been discontinued according to that MacUpdate link. However, [Captin](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/59718/captin) is a similar app which I tried and it works well, as of macOS Mojave.